# Missing stub error on mockito in flutter. Trying to use setString on mocked SharedPreferences

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, mockito, flutter-test, flutter-mockito

I'm trying to mock sharedPreferences using Mockito in my flutter project. Here is the error log.

```
package:mockito/src/mock.dart 190:7                                                                       Mock._noSuchMethod
package:mockito/src/mock.dart 184:45                                                                      Mock.noSuchMethod
test\feature\number_trivia\data\datasource\number_trivia_local_datasource_test.mocks.dart 67:14           MockSharedPreferences.setString
package:clean_arch_tdd/features/number_trivia/data/datasources/number_trivia_local_datasource.dart 31:30  NumberTriviaLocalDataSourceImpl.cacheLastNumberTrivia
test\feature\number_trivia\data\datasource\number_trivia_local_datasource_test.dart 51:18                 main.<fn>.<fn>

MissingStubError: 'setString'
No stub was found which matches the arguments of this method call:
setString('CACHED_NUMBER_TRIVIA', '{"text":"Test trivia","number":1}')

Add a stub for this method using Mockito's 'when' API, or generate the mock for MockSharedPreferences with 'returnNullOnMissingStub: true'.
```

The error refer to this line of code.

local_data_source_test.dart

```
test('should call sharedPreferences to cache the data', () {
      dataSource.cacheLastNumberTrivia(tNumberTriviaModel);
      final expectedJsonString = jsonEncode(tNumberTriviaModel.toJson());
      verify(mockSharedPreferences.setString(
          cachedNumberTrivia, expectedJsonString));
    });
```

local_data_source.dart

```
@override
  Future<void> cacheLastNumberTrivia(NumberTriviaModel triviaToCache) {
    return sharedPreferences.setString(
        cachedNumberTrivia, jsonEncode(triviaToCache.toJson()));
  }
```

It show that method setString from the mocked sharedPreferences is missing. I already run the pub command to generate the mocks. I also have some test case in the file that use the getString method. And it works fine.

Is there something I'm missing so I can't use the setString method? Or are there any solution to this problem?

Thx in advance.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or other text. Copy the original text to your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I actually figured it out, sorry for not posting the answer immediately.

I found myself forgot to call the stub for the setString method. Here is the code.

```
group('cacheNumberTrivia', () {
    const tNumberTriviaModel =
        NumberTriviaModel(number: 1, text: 'Test trivia');

    test('should call sharedPreferences to cache the data', () async {
      when(mockSharedPreferences.setString(any, any))
          .thenAnswer((_) async => true);
      dataSource.cacheLastNumberTrivia(tNumberTriviaModel);
      final expectedJsonString = jsonEncode(tNumberTriviaModel.toJson());
      verify(mockSharedPreferences.setString(
          cachedNumberTrivia, expectedJsonString));
    });
  });
```

The stub was actually this line:

```
when(mockSharedPreferences.setString(any, any))
          .thenAnswer((_) async => true);
```

I forgot to call the `when` method before verifying the result with `verify`, hence it throws an error.